# Android Class Cast Exception of ArrayList

Tags: android, class, exception, android-intent

I created a Class that `extends ArrayList<OtherClass>`. Then I put an instance of that class as an extra of Intent like `intent.putExtra("questionlist", questionsList);`In other Activity I get that extra like `questionsList = (QuestionList) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("questionlist");`and cast it up as shown in the code but it pops up `ClassCastException. What is problem here. Thanks.`

```
public void startTest(){
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.testznanja.TESTACTIVITY");
    intent.putExtra("player", player);
    intent.putExtra("numberofquestions", numberOfQuestions);
    intent.putExtra("numberofmistakes", numberOfMistakes);
    intent.putExtra("questionlist", questionsList);
    startActivity(intent);
}



private void initialize() {
    playerList = new PlayerList(this.getCacheDir());
    questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionText);
    questionText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    correctAnswers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionsAnswers);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.beginTest);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    testPlayer = (Player) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key");
    numberOfQuestions = getIntent().getIntExtra("numberofquestions", 0);
    numberOfMistakes = getIntent().getIntExtra("numberofanswers", 0);
    questionsList =  (QuestionList) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("questionlist");
    questionsList.shrinkToRandomQuestions(numberOfQuestions);
}




public class QuestionList extends ArrayList<Question>{

private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> answersList = new ArrayList<String>();

public QuestionList(Context c) {
    context = c;
}
```

}

Comment: post the code in a clean and readable format. thats  mess.

Comment: post the definiton of QuestionList, and the actual stacktrace. Also, why would you need to extend ArrayList?

Comment: I'm sorry, i posted code now.

Comment: Oh I just remembered, as a variable in QuestionList Class I have Context, can this be reason?

Comment: Your should post Question class definition too, but I suspect it is not serializable.

Answer (score 0):

`OtherClass` must be `Serializable` in order for you to pass it as a `Serializable` extra to the Intent.  It is not enough that `ArrayList<?>` is `Serializable`.